# Where is the regular expression syntax highlighting information stored for inline strings in Resharper 9?

Tags: regex, resharper, resharper-9.0

There's this really cool new set of features in resharper 9. Particularly regarding Regex and the syntax highlighting. [This post](http://hmemcpy.com/2014/10/regular-expression-enhancements-in-resharper-9/) gives a good overview of how it works.

Basically, by putting your cursor on any string, and choosing this context command:
[image: Before known as regex]

Will result in this highlighting: 
[image]

I want to know **where resharper stores the reference to that string**, and how it will then know it is a regular expression.

I can't find it in resharper settings anywhere (besides turning the feature on and off). Any idea where it could exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this information is stored in the [solution cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Configuring_Caches_Location.html), because after deleting the cache, the manually triggered highlighting of regex strings disappear.

Anyways, by using typed regexes, R# automatically highlights them:

[image: Regex field]

If you really have to use strings, you could alternatively use the following trick utilizing the [`RegexPattern` code annotation attribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#RegexPatternAttribute).

[image: RegexPattern attribute]

Comment: Oh! That is a clever way of going about it!